# OSX: iTunes won't play .ogg files over shared library

Tags: macos, itunes, home-sharing

I have an OSX 10.5 box that is sharing its iTunes library and another 10.6 box connecting to that library through iTunes. It works as expected except for ogg files. Those ogg files are visible and selectable in the shared library but will not play through the share on the client machine.
If I move the ogg files to the client machine they play locally just fine. They also play locally on the host machine. They just won't play through the iTunes share.

Is this a bug or some other known issue? Is there a fix, short of converting all ogg files to mp3?

Comment: When you play the files locally on the machine, is it through iTunes?

Comment: Yes, iTunes plays them locally.

Comment: Do those files in particular have strange permissions or is that the case for all ogg files?

Comment: What plugin do you have in iTunes that plays the ogg files? Perian? VNC? (Vanilla iTunes cannot play ogg files.)

Comment: @Jay_Booney - No strange permissions. This is the case with all ogg files.

Comment: @CajunLuke - No plugins that I'm aware of, but iTunes on both systems will play ogg files just fine, but only if those files are on the local filesystem.

Comment: @CajunLuke - scratch that, I dug a little deeper and see that the XiphQT plugin is installed (http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that iTunes doesn't use quicktime plugins when playing files over a network. Since it's not normally capable of playing Ogg files, you cannot over a network.

Your best bet will probably be to transcode to mp3. There may also be programs that will do this on-the-fly for streaming.

Comment: That iSucks. Thanks for the info though - at least I know *why*

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Xiph QuickTime Components](http://xiph.org/quicktime), then iTunes will accept .ogg files.